# Convert string from xml to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a XML file from which I read time stamps. When reading these time stamps using `.InnerText` I will get this for each node:

```
 2016  6  9  15  8  28
```

My goal is to convert that string into this format:

```
2016-06-09T15:08:28.000000+00:00
```

Is there any solution for doing this?

**XML** example:

[image: XML example]

Comment: If the format always stays te same, you could parse the string and use an constructor overload of the DateTime class to create a valid DateTime like the one you want. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You can try to use the `DateTime.ParseExact()` method to get a DateTime out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best method is to get every component of the date from the XML. If you want to start using the InnerText property, try to use this:

```
var input = "2016 6 9 15 8 28 ";
var parts = input.Split(new char[] { ' ' },
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(n => Int32.Parse(n)).ToArray();
var dt = new DateTime(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5]);
```

I prefer the method suggested by Alex above! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the string will always be in the same format you can use [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) to get a DateTime object.

```
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(innerText, "yyyy M d H m ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, parse year, month, day, hour, minute and second from your XML to integers, then use one of DateTime's constructors:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int seconds);
```

Then format your date using one of the [format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).